# Network share permission issues

Tags: windows, permissions

I have an IIS server running a site, appPool is running under local system, this is done because its easier to have full permissions to certificates and other file based resources on the local server.

Problem is when I try write or copy a file to a network share, permissions are obviously not in place on the remote system for the IIS server local system.

Is it possible to grant permissions on the remote system to include read/write or even full access to the IIS servers local system account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$

Answer (score 1):

The thing about the local system account is that it doesn't have network access -  by design. You'll need to run it under an account that does have network access.

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: @JL - No, it's not wrong. It's a deliberate design feature and has been that was since the account was first used in Windows. This is well known to all Windows admins and the information comes from Microsoft themselves.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an Active Directory domain the easiest way is this:

- create a user in domain
- give this user administrative credentials on the IIS server machine
- make the app pool run as this user
- add necessary permissions on the share (and filesystem) so the webapp can write files on the network share